# How to retrieve the length of a map whose values are true only?

Tags: firebase, dictionary, flutter, dart

I would like to retrieve the length of a map in firebase whose values are true only. I have retrieved a document snapshot and currently have

```
Text(post['upvotes'].length.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[100])
```

How do i get those whose values are true only?

```
class Post { //for forums


String title;
  String content;
  String timestamp;
  String imageurl;
  String username;
  String profilePicture;
  String documentid;
  String ownerid;
  Map<String, dynamic> saved = {};
  Map<String, dynamic> upvotes = {};
  


  Post(
    this.title,
    this.content,
    this.timestamp,
    this.imageurl,
    this.username,
    this.profilePicture,
    this.documentid,
    this.ownerid,
    this.saved,
    this.upvotes
    //this.image
  );

  Post.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) : 
  title = snapshot["title"],
  content = snapshot['content'],
  timestamp = snapshot['timestamp'],
  imageurl = snapshot['imageurl'],
  username = snapshot['username'],
  profilePicture = snapshot['profilePicture'],
  documentid = snapshot['documentid'],
  upvotes = snapshot['upvotes'],
  ownerid = snapshot['ownerid'],
  saved = snapshot['saved'];
}
```

Comment: What type is `post['upvotes']`?

Comment: @julemand101 i've uploaded the code for the post class. upvotes is of type Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: So what is the dynamic in this context? Just bool objects or some other kind of object?

Comment: @julemand101 just bool objects

Comment: If just bool object you can do: `upvotes.values.where((e) => e as bool).length`